# Converting Spectre.Console's Introduction example to F#

Tags: .net, f#, spectre.console

I'd like to use `Spectre.Console` in an F# console app. I'm trying to convert the [Introduction](https://spectreconsole.net/cli/introduction) example from C# to F#. Below is my attempt:

```ml
open System

open Spectre.Console.Cli

type AddSettings() =
    inherit CommandSettings()

    [<CommandArgument(0, "[PROJECT]")>]
    member val Project = "" with get, set

type AddPackageSettings() =
    inherit AddSettings()

    [<CommandArgument(0, "<PACKAGE_NAME>")>]
    member val PackageName = "" with get, set

    [<CommandOption("-v|--version <VERSION>")>]
    member val Version = "" with get, set

 type AddReferenceSettings() =
    inherit AddSettings()

    [<CommandArgument(0, "<PROJECT_REFERENCE>")>]
    member val ProjectReference = "" with get, set

type AddPackageCommand() =
    inherit Command<AddPackageSettings>()

    override _.Execute (context,  settings) = 0

type AddReferenceCommand() =
    inherit Command<AddReferenceSettings>()

    override _.Execute(context, settings) = 0


// Define a function to construct a message to print
let from whom =
    sprintf "from %s" whom

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    let message = from "F#" // Call the function
    let app = CommandApp()

    app.Configure(fun config ->
        config.AddBranch<AddSettings>("add", fun add ->
            add.AddCommand<AddPackageCommand>("package")
            add.AddCommand<AddReferenceCommand>("reference")
        )
    )

    app.Run(argv)
```

Unfortunately, I get the following compiler error:

```
The type 'AddPackageCommand' is not compatible with the type 'ICommandLimiter<AddSettings>'
```

[image: The type 'AddPackageCommand' is not compatible with the type 'ICommandLimiter']

Thank you for any and all help.

Comment: I'm using spectre.console.cli in fsharp for the cli in my repository (you might find the package SpectreCoff useful as well :)) https://github.com/EluciusFTW/SpectreCoff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I solved that issue:

1. Explicitly add `interface ICommandLimiter<AddSettings>` to the `Command` subclasses that use inheritance in the settings from `AddSettings`.
2. Change the `AddBranch` call to infer the generic argument by only annotating the `IConfigurator`'s type: `config.AddBranch("add", fun (add: IConfigurator<AddSettings>) -> ...`.

```
open System

open Spectre.Console.Cli

type AddSettings() =
    inherit CommandSettings()

    [<CommandArgument(0, "[PROJECT]")>]
    member val Project = "" with get, set

type AddPackageSettings() =
    inherit AddSettings()

    [<CommandArgument(0, "<PACKAGE_NAME>")>]
    member val PackageName = "" with get, set

    [<CommandOption("-v|--version <VERSION>")>]
    member val Version = "" with get, set

 type AddReferenceSettings() =
    inherit AddSettings()

    [<CommandArgument(0, "<PROJECT_REFERENCE>")>]
    member val ProjectReference = "" with get, set

type AddPackageCommand() =
    inherit Command<AddPackageSettings>()

    interface ICommandLimiter<AddSettings>

    override _.Execute (context,  settings) = 0

type AddReferenceCommand() =
    inherit Command<AddReferenceSettings>()

    interface ICommandLimiter<AddSettings>

    override _.Execute(context, settings) = 0


// Define a function to construct a message to print
let from whom =
    sprintf "from %s" whom

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    let message = from "F#" // Call the function
    let app = CommandApp()

    app.Configure(fun config ->
        config.AddBranch("add", fun (add: IConfigurator<AddSettings>) ->
            add.AddCommand<AddPackageCommand>("package") |> ignore
            add.AddCommand<AddReferenceCommand>("reference") |> ignore
        )
    )

    app.Run(argv)
```